# Desplegar una matriz de diagonales con numeros pares

Tags: java

Poseo un problema que involucra matrices, lo que necesito hacer es llenar una matriz de N*M de dimensión (es decir, de un número n de columnas y filas dados por el usuario), con números pares, lo cual ya eh conseguido. Mi incoveniente se genera cuando voy a desplegar dicha matriz, ya que cuando el numero de filas es mayos al de  las columnas, tengo un error el cual es este:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at diagonal.pkg2.Diagonal2.main(Diagonal2.java:40)
D:\Users\Jefferson\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1

Pero, en caso contrario, cuando la matriz es de forma n*m y las filas no superan al de las columnas o es cuadrada, no hay inconveniente
adjunto corridas de cada caso:

corrrida cuando el numero de filas es mayor al numero de columnas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí se presenta otro problema tambien, ya que justo despues de su diagonal principal, todos sus valores son cero(cosa que no deberia ser así)

corrida del programa, cuando el numero de filas es menor al de columnas y el error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como puedo solucionar estos problemas?
dejo el codigo:

```
   int filas;
int columnas;
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("Ingrese el nro de filas para la matriz: ");
filas=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
System.out.println("Ingrese el nro de columnas para la matriz: ");
columnas=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

//definimos las variables para almacenar la matriz y de control
int fila, columna, ultimaColumnaInicio, ultimaFilaInicio;
int matriz[][];
int valor = 2;
matriz = new int[filas][columnas];

ultimaColumnaInicio = columna = columnas - 1;
ultimaFilaInicio = fila = 0;
do {
  matriz[fila++][columna++] = valor;
  if (columna == columnas) {
    fila = 0;
    columna = --ultimaColumnaInicio;
  } else if (fila == filas) {
    fila = ++ultimaFilaInicio;
    columna = 0;
  }
  valor = valor + 2;
} while ((fila != filas));


for(int i=0; i < filas; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j < columnas; j++) {
        System.out.print(String.format("%3d", matriz[i][j]) +" ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: Has hecho la misma pregunta 2 veces  en un espacio de 1  hora. Por favor, elimina una de las 2 y da tiempo a que la gente pueda ver tu problema: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/216289/ayuda-con-matriz-nm-en-diagonal

Answer (score 1):

Logré una solución utilizando coordenadas, variables `X` e `Y` que se irán 'moviendo'; si vemos ese recorrido nos damos cuenta que hay un solo patron de movimiento, arriba-abajo diagonalmente.

Eso sugiere poner `X=-1` e `Y=cols-2` o si el array tiene una sola columna `Y=0` para posteriormente realizar ese único patron de movimiento de la forma `X++; Y++;` (*arriba-abajo en diagonal hacia la derecha*).

Ademas de esto **verificar** y **corregir** si nuestra coordenada está por fuera de las dimensiones de la matriz.

```
/*Si las coordenadas están por fuera se utiliza este método:
 *Coloca a X en la primera fila, después para Y busca posiciones
 *que estén en 0 (desocupadas), si no las encuentra, Y llegaría a -1
 *entonces procederia a corregir: X avanza 1 fila e Y pasa a la primera columna.
 */
private void tracking() {
    X=0;
    Y = cols > 1 ? cols-2 : 0;
    while(M[X][Y]!=0) {
      Y--;
      if(Y==-1) {
        X++;
        Y=0;
      }
    }
  }
```

Pero vayamos al código 100% completo:

```
public class Console {
  int[][] M; //El array.
  int X;     //Representa el eje X dentro de la matriz.
  int Y;     //Representa el eje Y dentro de la matriz.
  int C = 2; //Llevara la cuenta de los valores pares.
  int rows;  //Filas que se auto-generaran (random).
  int cols;  //Columnas que se auto-generaran (random).
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Console().fill();
  }

  private void fill() {
    rows = 1+new java.util.Random().nextInt(7);
    cols = 1+new java.util.Random().nextInt(7);
    System.out.printf("Rows: %d, Cols: %d%n",rows,cols);
    M = new int[rows][cols];
    X = -1;//Comienza por fuera de la dimension.
    Y = cols > 1 ? cols-2 : 0;//Depende si hay solo una o mas columnas.

    for(int k=0; k<rows*cols; k++) {
      X++;//Una linea abajo en la matriz.
      Y++;//Una columna a la derecha en la matriz.

      //Verificar si estamos por fuera de las dimensiones de la matriz.
      if(X==rows && Y==cols) {
        tracking();
      } else if(Y==cols) {
        tracking();
      } else if(X==rows) {
        tracking();
      }

      M[X][Y]=C;//Aplica al 2D Array el valor par.
      C+=2;
    }

    //Imprime en la Sout el resultado.
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
      for(int j=0; j<cols; j++) {
        System.out.print(M[i][j]+"\t");
      }
      System.out.printf("%n");
    }
  }

  //Busca, corrige y reposiciona los ejes X e Y en la matriz.
  private void tracking() {
    X=0;
    Y = cols > 1 ? cols-2 : 0;
    while(M[X][Y]!=0) {
      Y--;
      if(Y==-1) {
        X++;
        Y=0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Comparto los resultados generados aleatoriamente por este programa:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]